# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicação-web

blz?
Seguinte, estou com um problema com a exceção "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto", já busquei várias soluções, entretanto, nenhuma satisfaz e/ou corrige meu problema. Caso alguém puder me ajudar...

```
string usuario;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  //Área referente a consulta na base de dados em relação as metas da operadora

  SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@ "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_COOPERATIVE;Integrated Security=True;"); //Definição da string de conexão
  conexao.Open(); //É aberto a conexão com a base de dados

  //Recuperar o código da pessoa através de seu nome
  SqlCommand comandos2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT CODIGO_FUNCIONARIO from USUARIO where LOGIN_USUARIO='" + usuario + "'");
  comandos2.Connection = conexao;
  int cod_funcionario = Convert.ToInt16(comandos2.ExecuteScalar());

  //Por fim, pelo código do funcionário obtido, é iniciado a busca por suas metas
  SqlCommand comandos4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT VALOR_META from METAS where CODIGO_FUNCIONARIO='" + cod_funcionario + "'");
  comandos4.Connection = conexao;
  int metaArrecadacao = Convert.ToInt16(comandos4.ExecuteScalar());
  double valorSemanal = metaArrecadacao / 5;
  double valorDiario = metaArrecadacao / 30;

  //Por fim é exibido ao operador as suas respectivas metas
  //lblmensal.Text = Convert.ToString(metaArrecadacao);
  //lblsemanal.Text = Convert.ToString(valorSemanal);
  //lbldiaria.Text = Convert.ToString(valorDiario);

  //Eventos ao momento em que o form é carregado
}

protected void Page_InitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string usuario = String.Format(Session["usuario"].ToString());
  lblNome.Text = usuario;(AQUI OCORRE O ERRO)


}
```

O erro acontece na linha que referenciei. Quando executo inicialmente, não ocorre o erro, porém quando mudo de página em meu projeto, o erro acontece.

Comment: Precisaria ver outras partes do código, mas claramente não existe o campo `lblNome`. A não ser que o erro seja emoutro lugar. Tem outros problemas no código.

Comment: Opa, fala Maniero blz? Seguinte, esse erro aparece em todas as áreas referentes a manipulação com os labels da página

Comment: os labels estão com o atributo `runat="server"`?

Comment: Estão, esse erro ocorre quando eu saio da página inicial e vou para outra página dentro da aplicação. Se estou na página inicial, esse erro não é disparado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido pessoal!!! Até parece bobo, mas faz muito sentido, não estava tratando a relação de valores nulos, por isso a exceção era disparada. Para corrigir fiz a seguinte implementação:

```
namespace Projeto_Coopera
{
    public partial class dashboardOp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string usuario = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    usuario = String.Format(Session["usuario"].ToString());

                    if (lblNome != null)
                    {
                        lblNome.Text = usuario;
                    }

                    //Área referente a consulta na base de dados em relação as metas da operadora
                    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_COOPERATIVE;Integrated Security=True;"); //Definição da string de conexão
                    conexao.Open(); //É aberto a conexão com a base de dados

                    //Recuperar o código da pessoa através de seu nome
                    SqlCommand comandos2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT CODIGO_FUNCIONARIO from USUARIO where LOGIN_USUARIO='" + usuario + "'");
                    comandos2.Connection = conexao;
                    int cod_funcionario = Convert.ToInt16(comandos2.ExecuteScalar());

                    //Por fim, pelo código do funcionário obtido, é iniciado a busca por suas metas
                    SqlCommand comandos4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT VALOR_META from METAS where CODIGO_FUNCIONARIO='" + cod_funcionario + "'");
                    comandos4.Connection = conexao;

                    int metaArrecadacao = Convert.ToInt16(comandos4.ExecuteScalar());
                    double valorSemanal = metaArrecadacao / 5;
                    double valorDiario = metaArrecadacao / 30;

                    //Por fim é exibido ao operador as suas respectivas metas

                    //lblmensal.Text = Convert.ToString(metaArrecadacao);
                    //lblsemanal.Text = Convert.ToString(valorSemanal);
                    //lbldiaria.Text = Convert.ToString(valorDiario);

        }





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que você está usando equivocadamente `Page_InitComplete`

Veja o que diz parte da documentação:

> O InitComplete evento é chamado no final do estágio de inicialização da página. Neste estágio do ciclo de vida da página, todos declarados controles na página são inicializados, mas o estado da página ainda não está preenchido. Você pode acessar os controles de servidor, mas eles ainda não conterá informações retornadas do usuário.

Trecho retirado deste site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.page.initcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx

Aquele velho conselho: coloque um break point e verifique em que momento acessa esse método.

Comment: Fala SM_S , blz? Então, já tentei inserir esse trecho no Page_Load, entretanto, também ocorre o mesmo erro...

Comment: essa `label` existe?

Comment: Se tiver como, poste a parte do .aspx que o input é declarado no HTML, e o seu .designer.aspx

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

Comment: De início como havia comentado ele funciona sem maiores problemas, entretanto, quando acesso outra página de minha aplicação, o mesmo não funciona.